# Can Halal things become haram?

Tags: halal-haram

When I was a teenager (around 12-13 year old) I made some stupid dua. For example, I prayed to Allah to make some halal things haram in my life forever, as I did not like those things personally. Do these types of dua has any value?

I am adult now. I am having difficulty in my life thinking about these things. Can someone please answer my question? I will really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

If you see that something that is halal (not forbidden but not obligatory) is not good for you, you can leave it for you personally. There can be changes in the interpretation of the Word of God but the Word itself is not changing.

So, this type of dua does not have any value.

But observing that something that is not forbidden to everyone is not good for you and deciding not to do it on a personal basis is fine.